# element.replaceWith in link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have seen different example for rending an element in the link function

example one:

```
    var template = '<span><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel"></span>';
    element.html(template);
    $compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

example two:

```
    var template = '<span><input type="text" ng-model="ngModel"></span>';
    element.html(template);
    var el = $compile(element.contents())(scope);
    element.replaceWith(el);
```

i had tried 2-3 simple directives which works even without replacing the element. so what is the use case for the "element.replaceWith(el)". When is it necessary to user "element.replaceWith(el)" at the end of the link function?

Comment: Thanks your example one really helped me I am new to angularJS and needed someway to put a function inside the linking function and bind it to click event of another element 

this need to toggle the content of the directive 
with .replacewith it was toggling once and not working again but with your example one it is working perfectly

Comment: @Ali please also check this answer (it mike help you in getting few things clear): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22854581/validation-messages-are-not-getting-displayed-when-trancluding-a-directive-withi/22890796#22890796

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replacement is actually optional, and the final result won't be exactly the same:

**Your first example**: the element with your directive has the span as its only child

**Your second example**: the element with your directive is finally replaced with the span -> one level less in the DOM.

> All is about what you want in the DOM at the end. If you consider the original container with the directive is a useless wrapper only declaring a component, you will want to unwrap the content.

Comment: The directive templates I had given were only for example. What I really want to know is when should I use element.replace