# ngModel not updating in select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive rendering inputs based on a configuration sent by the server. Everything is working great except for the 'select' input.
No matter what I try, the ng-model does not update.
I have trimmed my code a lot to isolate the problem :

Javascript :

```
var myApp = angular.module('example', []);

    myApp.factory('DynamicData', [function() {
         return {
            data: {
              backup_frequency: 604800
            }
        };

    }])
    .directive('dynamicInput',
        ['$compile', 'DynamicData', function($compile, DynamicData) {

            /**
             * Render the input
            */
            var render = function render() {
                var input = angular.element('<select class="form-control" ng-model="inner.backup_frequency" ng-options="option.value as option.title for option in options"></select>');
                return input;
            };

            var getInput = function ()
            {
                var input = render();
                return input  ? input[0].outerHTML : '';
            };

            var getTemplate = function(){

                var template = '<div class="form-group">' +
                                'Select input ' +
                                '<div class="col-md-7">' + getInput() + '</div>' +
                            '</div>';
                return template;
            }; 

            return {
                restrict : 'E',
                scope: {
                    content:'=content',
                },

                link : function(scope, element, attrs) {
                    var template = getTemplate();

                    scope.options = [
                      {title: "Daily", value: 86400},
                      {title: "Weekly", value: 604800},
                      {title: "Monthly", value: 2678400},
                      ];
                    scope.inner = DynamicData.data;
                    console.info('inner data', scope.inner);

                    element.html(template);
                    element.replaceWith($compile(element.contents())(scope));


                }
            };
      }])
      .controller('FormCtrl', ['DynamicData', '$scope', function (DynamicData, $scope){
        $scope.app = {};

        $scope.save = function save() {
          $scope.value = DynamicData.data.backup_frequency;
          console.info('DynamicData', DynamicData.data);
        };
      }]);
```

HTML :

```
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.8" data-semver="1.3.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Dynamic Input :</h1>
    <div data-ng-controller="FormCtrl">
      <dynamic-input class="form-group" content="app"></dynamic-input>
      <span data-ng-bind="value"></span><br/>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="save()">Save</button>
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

A working plunker is available : http://plnkr.co/edit/mNBTJzZXjX6mLyPz6NCI?p=preview

Do you have any ideas why the ng-model in the select is not updated ?

EDIT : What I want to achieve is updating the variable "inner.backup_frequency" (the reference to my data object returned by my factory DynamicData). As you can see in the plunker, whenever I change the option in the select, the variable contained in the ng-model is not updated.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: do you want that`<span data-ng-bind="value"></span><br/>` to be different each time I click.. or the value in select options to be valid.. please explain

Comment: Hi, have you tried to fetch the on change event on the select and in javascript set the $scope.varaible and than $scope.$apply() just to see if it has something to do with the element being outside the $digest loop?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/22890796/446030 regarding order of compilation and placing within the dom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've fixed it. What you needed to do was not to replace the element's content with the compiled content, but rather replace it with the raw HTML and **only then** compile it.

```
element.html(template);
$compile(element.contents())(scope);
```

[Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ColO4TuRt5w4wklMXcmo?p=preview).

**EDIT**: I've edited your code to work without the directive:

[Plunker without directive](http://plnkr.co/edit/hVPXzN4aOYmkcSfdj989?p=preview).

**EDIT 2**: Also a version where it works with the directive, but without the compile:

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/OCNyoN97m1LwHWdGxN5a?p=preview).

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, It works. However, I'd would really like to lighten my DOM and remove the 'dynamic-input' HTML tag. Any ideas ?

Comment: @AlexandreNucera Yes, it looks like all the directive does is just produce hard coded HTML, why not just use that and lose the compile, etc ?

Comment: Ok this seems to do the trick : var e =$compile(template)(scope);
            element.replaceWith(e); ( I will award you the bounty tomorrow, I got to wait 21h)

Comment: @AlexandreNucera I also updated my answer, I included a new plunker to do the same thing without the directive. If it helps.. :)

Comment: I need the directive, I just dont want it to show up in the DOM. Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 13):

I had a similar issue and find if you directly bind ng-model to a scope variable as below, the scope variable selection somehow will not be updated.

```
<select ng-model="selection" ng-options="option for option in options">
```

Instead, define a view model in your scope and bind ng-model to a field of view model the view model field will be updated.

```
<select ng-model="viewmodel.selection" ng-options="option for option in options">
```

In your controller, you should do this:

```
app.controller('SomeCtrl', ['$scope'
    function($scope)
    {
        $scope.viewmodel = {};
    });
```

Comment: The take aways that were a huge help to me :
• the model needs to be a *property* on a scope variable - NOT a scope variable
• it is best to *not* assign the scope variable's property in JS - just reference it in the HTML and angular will create it and update it

Comment: Just remember: “The scope is not the model, the scope **refers** to the model” and “Whenever you have ng-model **there’s gotta be a dot** in there somewhere. If you don’t have a dot, you’re doing it wrong.” [more](http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/14/nested-scopes-in-angularjs.html)